# Snap to nearest marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

i am using GoogleMaps and i have 2 or more markers and they are draggable.
I want to snap 2 markers if they are near and merge them into 1.
is this possible ?

Can someone give me pointers .. how i can realize that ?

Comment: Is there something specific you were after with this question that I have missed?

Comment: Was it something I said? ;) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234

Comment: well .. someones else did it for me .. but he used your code .. so : thx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the [drag event](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarker.drag) on the [GMarker](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarker) object.  The trick is what do you do when you detect that you are near enough to another marker to snap them together.  I [played around a little](http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo13) with this and thought maybe hiding the currently dragged marker might be a good way to go.

```
GEvent.addListener(marker, "drag", function(point) {

    // iterate over your points and for each otherPoint...
    if (near (point, otherPoint))
    {
        // hide this marker
        marker.hide ();

        // move nearby marker to indicate merge?

        // then delete the dragged marker on the dragend (if it was merged)
    }
}
```

Not an entirely elegant solution, but it might suit your purposes.

**Edit**: I wondered if you were looking for the code to check nearby points, so I updated my example to do that:

```
function near (point1, point2)
{
    sw = new GLatLng(point2.lat() - 0.005, point2.lng() - 0.005);
    ne = new GLatLng(point2.lat() + 0.005, point2.lng() + 0.005);
    var bounds = new GLatLngBounds(sw, ne);
    if (bounds.contains (point1))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```