# Google Maps LatLngBounds Contains function always returns true

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to implement snap to Marker functionality while dragging another Marker.

I have a function that checks if two markers are 'close': (got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484578/snap-to-nearest-marker))

```
function arePointsNear(point1, point2) {
    var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(point2.lat() - 0.005, point2.lng() - 0.005);
    var ne = new google.maps.LatLng(point2.lat() + 0.005, point2.lng() + 0.005);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
    return bounds.contains(point1);
};
```

Now, on drag event of a marker, i do like this:

```
for (var index in allMarkers) {
    if(allMarkers[index] == marker) {
        continue;
    }

    var point1 = allMarkers[index].position;
    var point2 = marker.position;

    // This always returns true
    var isClose = arePointsNear(point1, point2);
}
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is working..the problem was inside my code. I was checking the positions of the same marker, not of two markers.