# Snapping to closest Marker Method always returning false

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

hopefully you can help me with this problem :)

***Here is my situation:*** 
Recently I have been working with the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=es). And with that I created a map, with *markers representing a recomendation on a travel route* on it. The *data of each of these markers are stored in my DB*, so that everytime I start my Webapplication I can represent them on the map. The markers however can be moved to another place on the map by the user, and so a new travel route is stored. 
Other than the recommended trip, *I also store other locations* of the same country in my DB. This is due to the abilty of  the user to move the other markers around to personalize his/her trip.

***Here is my Problem:***

With Javascript I listen to the Drop Event of the user and afterwards I get the new Location of that marker(location where it was dropped) and pass it on to another method:

```
//point1: contains marker which was dropped with its new location
//location: String containing the name of the place where the marker was dropped

arePointsNear: function (point1, location) {
    //result: Obj I pass on to method: trip.getHotels in order to get a List containing
    //all Hotels in the region 'location'
    var result = { 'markerLat': point1.position.lat(), 'markerLng': point1.position.lng(), 'loc': location };
    Trip.getHotels(result, function (hotels) {
        var found = false;

        //i: used as index of the hotels Array(res)
        var i = 0
        while (!found) {
            //sw: SouthWest, ne: NorthEast
            var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(hotels[i].lat - 1, hotels[i].lng - 1);
            var ne = new google.maps.LatLng(hotels[i].lat + 1, hotels[i].lng + 1);

                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);

                found = $.contains(bounds, point1);
                if (found) { break; }

                i++;
        }
    });
}
```

I am basically trying now to snapp the dropped marker to the closest hotel in my array. The Code above doesnt give out any error but the var *found* is always '*false*', even though I am pretty shure that the location of the dropped marker is within the *boundaries* of one of the hotels.

[**Link to Related question**: *Snap to nearest marker*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484578/snap-to-nearest-marker)

***Here my questions ...***
Why is found always false? Could it be that I am missing something? 

Does the problem lie with the [jquery contains](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) method, or with the following line:

```
var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(hotels[i].lat - 1, hotels[i].lng - 1);
```

I would be glad to hear your answers and I thank you in advance

> ***Edit!***
>   After getting my question answered I tried it with '.contains'. This for some reason still wouldnt work, so I have written a pretty simple method myself to detect the closest point or marker to another point or marker on the map. This I want to share with everyone who may be looking for just that:

```
//marker: Point to which you want to find the closest Point to
arePointsClose: function (marker) {
    //Trip: This is my Object and getHotels a method within my Object trip
    //With getHotels I get a List of Hotels from the Controller using AJAX
    //I pass a function to getHotels (For more information research: Callback)
    Trip.getHotels(function (hotels) {
        var closestPoint = undefined;
        var closestHotel = 0;
        //Here I start looping through my array of hotels
        for (var i = 0; i < hotels.length ; i++) {
            // Here I maka an if in one line and if the number resulting should be negative I multiply by -1 to evit that
            var x = ((marker.position.lat() - hotels[i].lat) < 0) ? (marker.position.lat() - hotels[i].lat) * (-1) : (marker.position.lat() - hotels[i].lat);
            var y = ((marker.position.lng() - hotels[i].lng) < 0) ? (marker.position.lng() - hotels[i].lng) * (-1) : (marker.position.lng() - hotels[i].lng);

            var point = x + y;
            //The point var is overwritten for the purpose of checking later in the if, if it is actually smaller than the actual closestPoint
            if (closestPoint == undefined || point <= closestPoint) {
                closestPoint = point;
                closestHotel = hotels[i];
            }
        }
        //Now closestPoint contains just what you wanted. Pass it on to another function now to maybe redraw the markers (and) their path
        //Trip.yourFunction

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [jQuery contains](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) function is mean to work with DOM elements, e.g. does this div contain that span:

```
$.contains('#thisDiv', '#thatSpan')`;
```

Not if a Google Maps LatLngBounds object contains a specific point.

For that, you need to do use the LatLngBounds' own `contains` function, e.g.:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);

found = bounds.contains(point1);
```

Comment: You are exactly right, the $.contains is only for DOM elements. I tried it out after the .contains didnt work, for some reason it would always give out an error. I ended up making another method to find the nearest point which I am probably going to include in an edit of my Question